# How to open the corresponding review item when viewing a question/answer?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

When browsing on Stack Overflow I often see questions with pending close/reopen votes, that I disagree with. But I can't express my disagreement because the corresponding review task is inaccessible from the question, so I can't click "leave open" or "leave closed".

[image: Close (1) - I disagree]

Is there an easy way to find the review task that is associated with a question from the question page?

This could help with the efficiency of the review process, because someone that has already read the question will handle the flags faster than someone that just landed on it through the review queue.

Comment: If you're a mod, you can get to it using some arcane UI feature. Otherwise, you are fresh out of luck.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - then maybe I should retag this question [feature-request]?

Comment: Sure, although there's at least [one such request on M.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114125/review-link-in-question-answers-itself) already.

Comment: The best you can do is to open the queue and try to filter to the close reason and the rarest tag used on the question. Just note that the question will have to have had the close vote for at least a day before it will appear in the queue (maybe a little less).

Answer (score 60):

With the availability of the new [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34441930/timeline) you can now find the completed reviews there. The url is `/posts/{id}/timeline`

[image: new timeline on posts]

#### Previous method to find a review

Searching for recent Close Votes Reviews (in reviews from other users only available for 10K-ers) are somewhat easy because not that many people use their review tasks. If I need to find a review I follow this approach:

1. make sure I visited the question (so it is in your browsers visited list)
2. and then open the [Review History](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history).
3. Glance over the page to spot a visited link
4. if no hit, goto the next page, repeat 3.
5. success!

[image: review history with visited links]

Ok, I admit this screams for a userscript... so here it is (most  useful for > 10K users, sorry)

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         find reviews
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.5
// @description  find reviews from the history pages 
// @author       rene
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/review/*/history
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/review/*/history
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/* global $: true */

(function($) {
    var hdr = $('.s-page-title--header'); // not a JS hook but there is nothing else to go on

    // search on single review page
    function searchPage(postid, page) {
        // get the specific page
        $.get(window.location + '/?page=' + page, function(data) {
            var $reviews = $(data),
                result = {},
                // check if post id is in the link
                $qlink = $reviews.find('#content a[href*="/questions/' + postid + '/"]'),
                $review;
            // maybe answers
            if ($qlink.length === 0) {
                   $qlink = $reviews.find('#content a[href*="/' + postid + '#"]');
            }
            if ($qlink.length > 0) {
                // find the review task by navigating up the dom
                // to the row
                // and then take the 3 table cell
                // which holds the a href to the reviewtask
                $review = $($qlink.parent().parent().find('td')[2]).find('a');
                // build our result object
                result = {text: 'found', url: $review.attr('href')};
                state = 0;
            } else {
                // stop if search needs to go beyond an insane amount of pages
                if (page < 400) {
                    // prevent getting throttled
                    if (state === 1) {
                        window.setTimeout( function () { searchPage(postid, page + 1);} , 500); // 500 ms
                        // some feedback
                        result = { text: 'page ' + page + '...' , url: window.location + '/?page='+page };
                    } else {
                        result = { text: 'stopped on page ' + page, url: window.location + '/?page='+page };
                        state = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    // bail out
                    result = { text: 'no results in 400 pages', url: window.location + '/?page='+page};
                    state = 0;
                }
            }
            // show result object
            $('#search-result').attr('href', result.url).text(result.text);
        });
    }

    var state = 0;
    // gets the postid from the input box
    function startSearch() {
        var inp = $('#search-review').val(),
            page = 1;
        if (state === 0) {
          $('#search-result').attr('href', '#').text('starting').show();
          searchPage(inp, page);
        }

        state++;
    }

    // if you hate how things looks, apply css fu here
    hdr.append(
        $('<div id="search-for-review"></div>')
        .css('display','inline-block')
        .append(
            $('<input id="search-review" type="text"/>'))
        .append(
            $('<input type="button" />&nbsp;')
            .prop('value', 'find review')
            .on('click', startSearch))
        .append(
            $('<a id="search-result"></a>').hide()));
}($));
```

The script is tested on Chrome with Tamper Monkey. See it in action [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVeGX.gif). I admit that it isn't directly from the question but is better that searching by hand.

The source is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/ReviewFinder.user.js), > version 0.3 also searches in other queues for either questions or answers.

If you are looking for reviews that took place more than a week ago you can use [this sede query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366230/find-all-reviews-for-a-post?postid=11388609) to find all reviews for a given post.

Comment: Nice! I just tested it and it seems to work (not sure why someone downvoted your answer). Still hope that someday we'll get a direct link so that it gets more exposure to the users, but in the meantime this looks like a pretty good workaround.

Comment: @user000001 the down vote came in on the first revision and to be honest, clicking through the history looking for a color difference can hardly be described as easy, so that revision wasn't really answering your question. Give the team 6 to 8 weeks to implement that...

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the SO close/open system is crude.

If you are reading a question and find a close or re-open votes you don't agree with, you'll have to wait until 4 other people have done the same incorrect conclusion as the first one, before you can cast a vote in the other direction.

Core problem is that those 5 people is not a majority vote. If you have one thousand SO veterans/meta nerds who view a post and disagree on the current close/re-open vote, they will still get outvoted by 5 sloppy "bandwagon" voters who just cast a brief glance at a post and then follow the previous close vote(s) without thought.

So whether a question gets closed or not doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the quality of the question itself; but rather by the amount of "bandwagoneers" that happen to read it. But luckily, most close voters out there behave, which is why the system works somewhat well.

A better system would have two options always present for users with enough rep: open and close. When there would be a total of 5 votes, the question would get opened or closed based on majority. And then the counter to 5 would reset, so that the same question can get opened/closed again.

Comment: This is essentially what is asked by this feature request [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close). It is tagged "status completed", but it's not really implemented.

Comment: @user000001 Apparently some mod thought gold badge "dupe hammer" was the solution to the problem. But dupe hammer is really unrelated to this, as it only applies to duplicates and only affects gold badge people.

Comment: @Lundin No, if you use the script you can find the review and then cast a leave open vote, that only needs two more in that case. And you can always run to the [SOVCR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if something gets closed wrongly. We are happy to help.

Comment: @rene That's really not something I'm going to bother with unless it gets integrated in the SO interface.

Comment: @Lundin I understand that. My offer to help out from the SOCVR room still stands ;)