# Checking posts review history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Is it possible to query on "data.stackexchange" for all reviews on a certain question/answer? If yes, how can I do it? If no, I request a feature.

Why? It would be very useful to learn about reviewing. There are sometimes questions which have a high view count, but low quality. It would be interesting/teaching to know why they weren't closed yet or have been reopened for some reasons.

Comment: You can query the `PostHistory` and `PostHistoryTypes` tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/542490) the PostHistory table as indicated by Stijn. You're interested in the Close and Reopen events, recorded as posthistorytypeid's 10 and 11:

```sql
select top 1000 ph.postid [Post Link]
     , name
     , min(p.closeddate) [closed on]
     , min(p.score) [score]
     , sum( case when posthistorytypeid = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as closed
     , sum( case when posthistorytypeid = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as reopen
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
inner join posthistorytypes pt on pt.id = ph.posthistorytypeid
where posthistorytypeid = 10 
or posthistorytypeid = 11
group by postid, name
order by sum( case when posthistorytypeid = 10 then 1 else 0 end)  desc
```

Another option is to query the [reviewtasks](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/542492) table

```sql
select top 1000
       r.postid as [Post Link]
     , count(*) as [review tasks]
     , min(p.score) as score
     , min(p.viewcount) as views
     , rtt.name
from reviewtasks r
inner join reviewtasktypes rtt on rtt.id = r.reviewtasktypeid
inner join posts p on p.id = r.postid
where rtt.id in (2 ,6 ) -- close , reopen
group by postid 
    , rtt.name
order by count(*) desc
```

To find more info on which tables you can use see [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)

If you're interested in your own review performance against your peers you can use the [Consensus review script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100).

You can't find if a post is currently under review. That was available for a few days from the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/334969/timeline) but despite that some of us liked that feature the majority felt it gave posts an uneven chance for being reviewed by un-biased eyes so [that feature was disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items). I have a very rough review post finder script [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/578411)