# How do I know if edit is good enough to cause reopening of question

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

Having recently posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409738/can-angularjs-always-replace-jquery it was put on hold as primarily opinion-based.

That seems right, because I had a subquestion about which general things to watch out for, so I made an edit and removed it to make the question less opinion-based.

[How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) states that:

> Editing the body of a question within five days of closure will add it to the Reopen Review queue, where people with the the ability to cast reopen votes will assess it. A question can only be added to the Reopen Review queue once per closure via editing.

So my question is currently in the Reopen Review queue - will I know if it's accepted/rejected, and if it is still too opinion-based, will I have another chance to edit it and send it to the Reopen queue?

Comment: FWIW, people voted to [leave it closed](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14750693).

Comment: @vaultah how did you find that? Is there a way to search for reviews on specific questions?

Comment: @MartinSmith I searched the [history page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) for the question title

Comment: @MartinSmith there's also the timeline which is easier.

Comment: @Braiam thanks, I didn't realise that shows up on there http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41409738/timeline. Definitely looks easier than going through the history, especially if looking for something not recent.

Comment: @MartinSmith for still on-going reviews you can use [this userscript](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/578411) I wrote.